# How To change long date to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

How To change Long Date To  short Date

E.g (Sunday, January 10, 2018)--Long Date
E.g (2018-01-10)

Comment: cast(yourdate, as date)

Comment: The Error i got is "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".

Comment: You were not clear on the type of the data. You're asking how to convert a long date expressed as a string, to a short date expressed as a string? Or to a short date as a 'date' or 'datetime' or 'datetime2' type? Please be specific. Examples would be helpful, as well as what you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the string to a date, once you get rid of the day-of-week:

```
select convert(date, stuff(longdate, 1, charindex(' ', longdate), ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(DATE, 'May 23 2019',101)
```

or

```
select convert(DATE, 'January 10 2018',101)
```

January 10th 2018 was a Wednesday

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused; properly stored a date is just a date - a number, if you like, or the count of days (and fractions of days) since some point in time. It doesn't have any text in its internal representation and cannot be shortened.

When you select it in a query the query tool has to represent it somehow and for that it will format it into a string that you'll interpret as an entry on your wall calendar. For the most part we should avoid getting the db to format anything, because fornatting is the job of the presentation layer; the website that pulled your date out of the db and now has to make it look like the German way of writing a date because Hans Schmidt is logged in, but later format it as American when John Doe is browsing

If you're desperate to format it in the db use

```
FORMAT(thedate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Or maybe

```
LEFT(CONVERT(thedate, varchar, 120), 10)
```